# HTML5 multi="true" tag doesn't work

Tags: eclipse, html

i use Eclipse kepler

in dynamic web project

i create html(HTML5) file and use code for Multi select file upload system

```
<input type="file" multiple="true" />
```

but can't select multiple with ctrl+click

and my eclipse has warning

```
Multiple annotations found at this line : 
-Undefined attribute value(true)
-Undefined attribute value(true)
```

any suggestion?

Comment: do you mind to share the webcode?

Comment: Try `multiple="multiple"` instead

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it does not work, then the reason is that you are using a browser that does not support the `multiple` attribute, such as IE 9. To deal with such browsers, you can add some JavaScript that tests whether the input element has the `multiple` property and if it does not, creates some additional file input elements (possibly in a loop that lets the user specify any number of files).

The warning should really be an error message, since `true` is not a valid value for the `multiple` attribute. As @IlmoEuro explains, the value should be empty or `multiple`. However, the value has in practice no impact; browsers recognize just the attribute name and ignore the value (even if you write `multiple="false"` for example).

Answer (score 2):

You need to use the attribute's name as its value:

> If the attribute is present, its value must either be the empty string
>   or a value that is an ASCII case-insensitive match for the attribute's
>   canonical name, with no leading or trailing whitespace.

(http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/infrastructure.html#boolean-attributes)

In other words, just use:

```
<input type="file" multiple>
```

or

```
<input type="file" multiple="multiple">
```

Comment: <input type="file" multiple="multiple"/> and <input type="file" multiple/> just select a file too :(

Comment: oh.. that web browser problem :) change chrome every thing work fine